# Disable Interceptor via deployment descriptor

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, interceptor

Scenario: 
@PerformanceMeasureInterceptor at various methods & classes throughout the code. This does what the name suggests...

Of course this should not be active at production. So how can an "annotation interceptor" be disabled for deployment?

Those are so far my ideas:
- cut out via pre-processing from all java files before compilation for production
- use only via deployment descriptor (no annotations) and change it there before deployment

Both are a little bit uncomfortable...

Answer (score 0):

You should try writing a CDI extension that let you add the interceptors in compilation-time only if some condition (environment) is met.

Comment: Hm, this is not what I want. The Annotations should be in the code and just be ignored depending on some config.